# LibGDX batch.draw() rotation and atan2() angle compatibility?

Tags: java, math, libgdx

There seems to be a calculation glitch of some sort when using `Math.atan2()` to calculate an angle and then using that angle in the rotation of texture using `batch.draw()`. A `System.out` has been used and it has been confirmed that `Math.atan2` is giving a wrong angle.

**Code:**

```
public void mouseAngle(int x, int y) {
    mouseAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(frame.getRegionHeight() / 2 - y, frame.getRegionWidth() / 2 - x));

    System.out.println(mouseAngle);
}
```

the two variables passed in, `int x` and `int y` are the mouse's `x` and `y` coordinates given by `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()`

The texture, `Assets.stand` is drawn like:

```
batch.draw(Assets.stand, bounds.x, bounds.y, frame.getRegionWidth() / 2, frame.getRegionHeight() / 2, frame.getRegionWidth(), frame.getRegionHeight(), 1, 1, mouseAngle, true);
```

Where `frame.getRegionWidth()` is the width of the texture and `frame.getRegionHeight()` is the texture height.

This is a sample output with the mouse directly on top of the player (character in the middle of the window):[image]

As it can be observed, the angle, when the mouse is directly on top of the player, is calculated to be -148. The angle is wrong for all angles when the mouse is circled around the player.

**The Question:** Is the method I am using to find the angle flawed? If so, what other functions/methods in Java can I use to find the angle? If not, is the problem due to the way I am drawing the texture?

Comment: Math.atan2 takes in `(Double y, Double x)` not `(int y, int x)`.

Comment: Doesn't matter, calculations "work" no matter the variable type

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your first input:

```
frame.getRegionHeight() / 2 - y
```

`frame.getRegionHeight()/2` is going to get you to a point in a line across the screen (horizontally). Now if you subtract a Y value that is greater than this value you will end up with a negative. In the case you show the mouse point is below the halfway point and therefore the first input is a negative value. Same case can be applied on the second input for the x.

You will need to fix the problem with getting negative distances.

Comment: This does not fix the problem. I used `Math.abs` to ensure that the distances are positive and have calculated the angles based on the positive lengths. I added 90, 180, 270 to the angle based on the position of the mouse and the problem persists.

Comment: @ylun.ca what does `frame.getRegionHeight() / 2 - y` and `frame.getRegionWidth() / 2 - x` return?

Comment: As stated above, coordinate of the middle of the texture subtracted from the mouse's y coordinate. So in other words, the distance between the texture and the mouse in terms of y

Comment: @ylun.ca No I mean did you actually check what value it returns?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work is because of how you get the y-coordinate of the mouse. Unfortunately, you have to take the difference of the y-coordinate of the mouse and the screen height since the y-coordinate of the mouse is in y-up and that makes the coordinate flipped.